# How to get item value when editItem function is called in jsGrid

Tags: javascript, json, jsgrid

in my jsGrid config, I have called `editItem` function like this:

```
            editItem: function(item) {
                var $row = this.rowByItem(item);
                if ($row.length) {
                    console.log('$row: '+JSON.stringify($row));
                    this._editRow($row);
                }
            },
```

at `console.log`, I get result :

```
{
  "0": {
    "jQuery223061031009408811742": {
      "JSGridItem": {
        "myColumn1": "AB",
        "myColumn2": "BC",
        "myColumn3": "CD",
      }
    },
    "jQuery223061031009408811741": {
      "events": {
        "click": [
          {
            "type": "click",
            "origType": "click",
            "guid": 67,
            "namespace": ""
          }
        ],
        "dblclick": [
          {
            "type": "dblclick",
            "origType": "dblclick",
            "guid": 68,
            "namespace": ""
          }
        ],
        "mouseover": [
          {
            "type": "mouseover",
            "origType": "mouseenter",
            "data": null,
            "guid": 69,
            "namespace": ""
          }
        ],
        "mouseout": [
          {
            "type": "mouseout",
            "origType": "mouseleave",
            "data": null,
            "guid": 70,
            "namespace": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "selector": "",
  "context": {},
  "length": 1
}
```

My real fields are inside `jQuery223061031009408811742 -> JSGridItem`

How can I get those values with function in jsGrid ? or maybe there is builtin function in JSON to solve that?

Note: field `jQuery223061031009408811742` always changed every time page reload, so I can't hardcode the field name to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get item from a row reading jQuery data `JSGridItem` field:

```
var item = $row.data("JSGridItem");
```

But it's not clear why you are redefining `editItem` method. I would suggest using callback [onItemEditing](http://js-grid.com/docs/#onitemediting) instead.